# jquery + datalist

Tags: jquery, datalist

I am not familiar to jquery, and want to get ID of controls i have in datalist so that i can use them.

Comment: you should probably use the tag jquery instead of jqeury

Comment: please post some code of what you are trying to do - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read about selectors, and you can name your html tags accordingly,

Start reading here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

You can then bind your controls like such...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('div[class=whateverClass]').each(function (index) {
      $(this).bind('click', {}, function (event) {
           alert('clicked!');
      }
});
```